# using math symbols to write this

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

u and v can have components (they are vectors in 2D) that are both positive real numbers or 0, or u and v can have components that are both negative real numbers or 0

is this okay?

$u,v \in R^+\cup \{0\}$ and $u,v\in R^-\cup \{0\}$, not sure how to really incorporate vectors into this math expression, help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about like this:
$$
u, v \in \{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 \geq 0\} \,\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,\, u, v \in \{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 \leq 0\}
$$
Its not too short but its clear.

Comment: So is this saying that, for a component of the vectors u and v, if it's positive then the other vector component must be positive? or vice versa for negatives

Comment: Not exactly. $\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0\}$ literally translates to: "all $(x_1, x_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that both coordinates are greater than or equal to $0$. In other words its the set of all vectors with non negative coordinates. The first part "$u, v \in$" just means they are an element of the set of vectors I just described. So the whole thing translates to $u, v$ are vectors with non negative coordinates (similar for the second line) ... which is what you wanted right?

Comment: I was aiming for the x component of u and v are both >=0 or <=0 and the y component is independent of that so it can be >=0 or <=0 for both vectors
when I read x1,x2 I assumed those were the same components of the vectors u,v

so I could have a vector (3, -4)=u and (5,-3)=v where their components are the same sign

Comment: @user2514022 I see. I'll fix my answer and see if its what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There is not even a standard way to denote nonnegative real numbers, see [How does one denote the set of  all positive real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27968/how-does-one-denote-the-set-of-all-positive-real-numbers), hence I very much doubt there's a standard notation for "vectors with both components nonnegative". I would guess something like

$$
\mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}_0^+
$$

but even that is not very clear. Why not just write it as

$$
u,v \in \{v | v \in \mathbb{R}^2, v_1 \cdot v_2 \ge 0\}
$$

or even

$$
u,v \in \{(x,y) | x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x \cdot y \ge 0\}
$$