# Bijection between $\{x^2: x \in R \}$ and $\{x: x \in R\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let's consider two sets:
$A := \{x^2: x \in R\}$ and $B:= \{x: x \in R\}$.

In my opinion its very intuitive that those two sets have exactly the same cardinality.
In other words there has to be a bijection $g$ between $A$ and $B$ but I couldn't find proper form of $g$. I tried to pick $g(x) = x$ or $g(x) = \sqrt x$ but none of them works (second example doesn't work because domain differs).

Could you please help me finding this bijection?

Comment: Maybe, observing that $\exp(B)=A\setminus\{0\}$ could help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602865/show-that-set-of-real-numbers-is-equipotent-to-the-set-of-positive-real-numbers, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654026/real-numbers-and-positive-real-numbers-have-same-cardinality

Comment: What about $g(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{x+1}\right)$

Comment: The two sets are not homeomorphic, so your bijection cannot be continuous.  Of course, there are many discontinuous functions to try.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu that is not defined for $x=1$

Comment: In the question, does $\ R\ $ mean $\ \mathbb{R},\ $ the set of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, it means set of real numbers

Comment: The consensus on this site is to use \Bbb R for the reals, and similarly \Bbb Q, \Bbb Z, \Bbb N.

Comment: Exercise: Show that a bijection $g:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ cannot be continuous. BTW this will not answer your Q but it will keep you from trying to find a continuous $g$.

Comment: What about $g(x)=\frac{(2\lfloor x\rfloor+3)(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}-3}{4}+x-\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: Correct expression is $g(x)=\frac{(2\lfloor x\rfloor+1)(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}-1}{4}+x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_0=[0,1]$ and $A_n=(n,n+1]$ for $n\in \Bbb Z^+.$ Let $B_0=[0,1]$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $B_{2n}=(n,n+1]$ and let $B_{2n-1}=[-n,1-n)$. For each non-negative integer $n$, map $A_n$ bijectively onto $B_n.$

Comment: A set-theorist would instead just say "Use the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem." (a.k.a. Cantor-Bernstein, a.k.a. Schroeder-Bernstein). There is a long complicated proof of it and a short simple proof.  If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are injective then there exists a bijection $h:A\to B.$

Answer (score 0):

$A := \{x: x \in \mathbb{R}\ \text{ and }\ x\geq0\}$ and $B:= \mathbb{R}.$

Now we need to find a bijective map from $A$ to $B$. After fiddling around with some sketches, I found the bijective function $\ g: A\to B\ $ defined by:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{n}{2} + (x\mod1), &\ x\in [n,n+1),\quad \text{for each even integer}\ n\geq 0\\
 -\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) + (x\mod1), &\ x\in [n,n+1),\quad \text{for each odd integer}\ n\geq 0\\
\end{cases}
$

I'm not sure this is the clearest way to write that function, so someone feel free to  amend this to make it simpler/read better.

Comment: It can be written in one expression with floor. See my last comment (I've made mistake in previous comment and lost one interval)