# Clarification for a simple argument in an inequality

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Suppose $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are such that $$ a \leq b \\ c \leq d \\ ac = bd $$ then is the following true? $$ a= b \\ c = d $$

Attempt:

Suppose not true, i.e. $a < b$ or $c < d$, then we have $ac < bd$ thus contradicting the fact that $ac=bd$. Thus $a= b$ and  $c = d$.

So, is my argument correct? Sorry for posting this if this is a **trivial** fact.

Comment: It's fine for me.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the confirmation. Should I leave this post as it is or delete it? Asking this since this may be trivial for some and they might downvote the same. What do you suggest?

Comment: I think you need to consider that a and c need not be positive.  -1 < 1.  -2 < 2  and (-1)(-2) = 1x2 so no.  But if you have $0 \le a \le b$ and $0 \le c \le d$ then you would have $a < b \implies ac < bc < bd$ so $ac =bd $ would have your result.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you. But notice that $\mathbb{R}^+$ I had in the question details.

Comment: Ah... then you are golden.   Remember $x < y; b > 0 \implies bx < by$ and so $a < b \implies ac < bc \le bd$ etc....

Comment: @Lohith-kumar I'd rather write that as $\,a,b,c,d \gt 0\,$ to make it unambiguously clear that all numbers are assumed to be strictly positive. The notation $\,\mathbb{R}^+\,$ can sometimes be used to refer to the non-negative reals, including $\,0\,$ (in which case the assertion fails).

Comment: I think it's a example of a proof by contrapositive. It might be helpful to those who confuse contrapositive and proof by contradiction.

Comment: @dxiv: positive real numbers should be denoted $\mathbf R^{+*}$. $\mathbf R^+$ is used for the non-negative.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "trivial" although it is easy.  And even with stating $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R^+$ it is *still* important to pin down the precise conditions.  As $a = b = 0$ yeilds no conclusion about $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @Bernard Good point.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Bernard There are quite a few different opinions and notations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27968/how-does-one-denote-the-set-of-all-positive-real-numbers) for example. It's always safest to define the terms whenever there is even a remote chance of ambiguity.

Comment: i think in this case, we need to specify conditions.  There are a finite number of conditions between whether a,b,c,d can be pos, neg, or zero, but the spirit of this result applies to strictly positive with specific exceptions figured out directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, FINAL final answer:

If $0 \le a \le b$ and $0 \le c \le d$ then

$ac \le bc$ with equality holding only if $a = b$ or $c = 0$.

And $bc \le bd$ with equality holding only if $c = d$ or $b= 0$.

So $ac \le bd$ with equality holding only if one of the four occur:

1) $a = b$ and $c = d$

2) $a =b$ and $b = 0$ so $a = b  =0$.

3) $c = 0$ and $c= d$ so $c = d = 0$.

4) $c =0$ and $b= 0$ and $0 \le a \le b = 0$ so $a = b = c = 0$

So if $ac = bd$ then either i) $a=b$ and $c=d$ or ii) $a=b=0$ or $c=d=0$.

And if $ac = bd \ne 0$ then $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Otherwise $ac < bd$.

Comment: Got it. But usually $\mathbb{R}^+=\{x\geq 0 ~|~ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I overlooked that you had specified that.  It's important to make such distinctions.  With such distinctions, your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Ah!  Consider $a = b = 0$ and $c$ and $d$ are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: let $b=ax, x\ge 1$ and $d=cy, y\ge 1$. Then:
$$ac=bd \Rightarrow ac=axcy \Rightarrow xy=1, x\ge 1, y\ge 1 \Rightarrow x=1, y=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$0=bd-ac=bd-bc+bc-ac=b(d-c)+c(b-a)\geq0.$$

Hence, for positive variables we have $a=b$ and $c=d$.

If our variables are non-negatives we need $b(d-c)=0$ and $c(b-a)=0$, which gives some cases.